# How do I get the property value from a container view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have 1 UIViewController that contains a UIContainerView and a UIButton.
Also, I have a UITableViewController (It has a UITextField and a UITextView) that is embedded in the UIContainerView in the UIViewController.

I'm trying to get the string values that will be available in TextField and in TextView.

[image]

I tried to use the segue to get the properties values, but I failed to do so, see the code below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TVCSegue" {
        let containerTVC = segue.destination as? FieldsTVC
        self.textField.text = FieldsTVC?.textField?.text
        self.textView.text = FieldsTVC?.textView?.text
    }
}
```

> The code above has 'textField' and 'textView' as properties in the UIViewController to assign the values to.

But I believe that it doesn't work as I get the values before they changes. Please provide me with a functional way to do so.

Comment: Share your code, as segue is most easy & possible way to do it.

Comment: There's too little information. You mention a UITableViewController that segues to another UIViewController with fields, which does not reflect the picture above.

Comment: @GiorgioR. I have edited the question with further details.

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar please check the question as I've edited it.

Comment: It's still unclear, but I see at least two problems: 1. you are assigning values (text) not retrieving them from an object (containerTVC) but from the related type (FieldsVC); 2. you are assigning values right before performing a segue (that is: right before going to another scene), so even if they were assigned, how would you see them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your main view loads, the *container* performs a segue to its assigned initial / root ViewController. At that point, you can get a reference to it:

```
var theFieldsTVC: FieldsTVC?
```

Now, in prepare for segue, assign that variable:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "TVCSegue" {

        if let vc = segue.destination as? FieldsTVC {
            theFieldsTVC = vc
        }

    }
}
```

Then, you can:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    self.textField.text = theFieldsTVC?.textField?.text
    self.textView.text = theFieldsTVC?.textView?.text

}
```

Comment: @DonMag IF I have two ViewControllers in a ContainerView, which the parent view loads the first ViewController loads/is called and displayed. Is it possible to get a reference to the second ViewController that can display, via a segmented controller, so that I can preload its textfields values!?

Comment: BTW this does not work... you should either use protocols or completion handler.

Comment: @FamicTech - the OP asked how to get values from a controller embedded in a `UIContainerView` when tapping a button in the root controller. Protocols / completion handlers would not apply in this case. I posted a full working project to demonstrate this solution here: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerValues